# Modifying a rails model at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, metaprogramming

on a previous question, I was searching for a way to 
dynamic valitating my models.

[Advice on "Dynamic" Model validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640964/advice-on-dynamic-model-validation)

The solution that I got working is:

```
def after_initialize        
  singleton = class << self; self; end

  validations = eval(calendar.cofig)

  validations.each do |val|
    singleton.class_eval(val)
  end
end
```

On my actual app, I have 2 models

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar

  def after_initialize        
    singleton = class << self; self; end

    validations = eval(calendar.cofig)

    validations.each do |val|
       singleton.class_eval(val)
    end
 end

end
```

As you can see, the validation code that should be added to the Event class lies on the Calendar field "config".

Works fine for a existing Event, but doesn't for a new record. That's because, at the time that after_initialize is called, the association doesn't exists yet.

I can't find a way to do that besides putting the config values on Event itself.

Any advices?

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run your validation code during the validation phase, not the initialize phase.  Try this:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar

  validate do |event|
    validations = eval(calendar.cofig)
    validations.each do |val|
      eval(val)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Tried and it redirects me to the create view. Am I missing something?

Comment: Depending on how your controller is wired that's probably due to validation failing.  I would check the validation code that's being run "on-the-fly" and make sure it is only adding to the errors collection if there is indeed an error.  Also make sure that no code is setting the "valid" attribute as Rails sets this automatically based on the value of the "errors" collection.

Comment: My test was with a simple "validates_presence_of"